# Which method acts as the main in Visual studio 2013 Web App (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, program-entry-point

I am creating a Web app with `ASP.NET` using `Visual Studio 2013`. In normal console programs, `main()` method will be the first to be run.

In a Web app, I realise there are numerous files. **Which file/method will be the first to be executed when I run the project?** I am asking this because I wanted to test my codes, but I just can't find a place for testing out my codes. I tested my codes in several different files, but they are not executed.

Currently I have BusinessLogicLayer, DataAccessLayer and the main project Folder. Each folder have many more folders containing many more files.

Please cut me some slack if this question is too easy as I am very new to `C#`.

I am not doing testing, I just want to create a simple Web App. But which file/method will get run first?

Comment: The first method to run would be `Application_Start` in Global.asax, but that is probably not the answer you're looking for. What would you like to test and how do you test it? Which framework do you use (WebForms, MVC)?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api check this article probably can help you !

Comment: @CodeCaster I am using .net framework 4.5 and when I start a new project, I select ASP.NET Wep Application.

Comment: @CodeCaster To keep my question simple. I just want to ask which method()/ class will be the first be get executed everytime I run my project?

Comment: I answered that in my first comment.

Comment: Just as side comment, if you want to test your application logic unit testing is the way to go, or even just rolling up a new console app and executing code there.

Comment: @CodeCaster There is no `Application_Start` in the project folder.

Comment: It should be in Global.asax, but only if you created it and added the method to it. That's why I asked for more information. In WebForms you're probably looking for the Load event of the page you want to test, in MVC you want the action method that you're calling. Again, what exactly are you trying to do? How do you want to test it?

Comment: @CodeCaster I only have several .aspx files in the project folder. Where should I create the c# files so that I can run my c# codes (e.g. using c# codes to connect to database)?